# Calculating force from change in momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum

I'm building a simple test bench for cyclical application of force. Instead of near static load I would like to apply the force in form of impulse via a drop of mass from a defined height.

Force can be calculated from change in momentum, the only unknown is the time of the application of the force.

My idea was to strap an accelerometer on the weight and see how long the acceleration cycle is.

Has anyone tried anything similar?

Comment: If you go by a change in momentum and time, then you get the _average_ force and not the actual force. This might make a difference for you.

Comment: Also note that the impact signal propagates at the speed of sound in the material, which can be as high as 5000 m/s which means your accelerometer resolution must be sufficient to capture all the dynamic effects.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.